# Fundamental gap for Schrödinger operator

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, ap.analysis-of-pdes, sp.spectral-theory, linear-pde

Consider $ \Omega$ a smooth bounded domain in $ \mathbb R^N$.
I am interested in the gap between the first and second eigenvalues of the operator $ -\Delta + V(x)$.    Let $ \phi_1>0$ and $ \phi_2$ be the first and second eigenfunction for this operator and so
$$ -\Delta \phi_i  + V(x) \phi_i = \mu_i \phi_i $$ in $ \Omega$  with $ \phi_i=0$ on $ \partial \Omega$.

So I am interested in getting a lower bound on $ \mu_2 - \mu_1$.

The ‘fundamental gap conjecture’ is related to an explicit lower bound on this quantity.    My interest is to not assume $V$ convex (many consider $V$ convex)  but I can assume ‘semi-convex’;  ie.  $V(x)+ c \lvert x\rvert^2$ convex for some $C>0$.

My interest is any sort of explicit positive lower bound on $\mu_2-\mu_1$;  but I don't care at all if its optimal.

Comment: does "semiconvex" exclude a double-well potential? if it does not, there is nothing from preventing two nearly degenerate eigenvalues, one from each well.

Comment: not sure what nearly degenerate eigenvalues means?   i assume it means you can make $ \mu_2 = \mu_1$ arbitrarily small?  (in any case,  no i can't exclude the double well).

Comment: in a symmetric double well potential the difference $|\mu_2-\mu_1|$ is exponentially small in the thickness of the barrier that separates the two wells.

Comment: I meant to write $ \mu_2-\mu_1 $ small...   okay, thanks for the result.  This is what i was looking for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to consult [Proof of the Fundamental Gap Conjecture](https://arxiv.org/abs/1006.1686) where it is shown that
$$
\mu_2 - \mu_1 \geq \frac{3\pi^2}{D^2}
$$
where $D$ is the diameter of $\Omega $.

Comment: doesn't this assume convex $\Omega$?

Comment: Yes, sorry it does.

Comment: Without the convexity assumption, is such a bound on the gap possible?

Comment: I've been told that a counter example to a lower bound in the case no convexity of $\Omega$ is assumed is given by two balls joined by a thin neck. Perhaps this is similar to the double well potential? But note here the problem is with the domain and not the potential.